# point Azure subdomain name application to another IP Server

Tags: azure, record

I have a system that use the Authentication of Azure, i have deployed the AD in Azure, now to consume the OAuth2 i need to have the application hosted in the same Azure.

I have created the Application with name (testapp.azurewebsites.net) now this testapp need to point to another Server, so when i enter on the url it should resolve another IP and run the application hosted on that server.

I have no found anything in AZURE to poin this testapp to an A record IP, is there a way to do this?

testapp.azurewebsites.net point to 192.168.0.12

Answer (score 0):

## Use Redirect

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testapp\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://192.168.0.12/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

### Step 1

[image]

### Step 2

[image]

### Step 3

[image]

### Step 4

[image]

### Step 5

[image]

### Step 6

[image]

### Step 7

[image]

### web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

- [How to Redirect the default *.azurewebsites.net domain to your custom domain on Azure Web Apps – Zain Rizvi](http://zainrizvi.io/blog/block-default-azure-websites-domain/)

Comment: This will redirect, i need the subdomain name to be used on the ip 192.169.0.12

Comment: Ip 192.168.0.12 is private ip ? Do you want to redirect to your localhost?

Comment: ip 192.168.0.12 is a public one that is hosted in a VM on AmazonAWS